# Vibe.d basic form validation

Tags: validation, d, vibed

I have a post create method:

```
void gönderiyiOluştur(HTTPServerRequest istek, HTTPServerResponse yanıt)
{
    render!("gönderiler/oluştur.dt")(yanıt);
}
```

and a post store method like this:

```
void gönderiyiKaydet(HTTPServerRequest istek, HTTPServerResponse yanıt)
{
    auto başlık = istek.form["baslik"];
    auto içerik = istek.form["icerik"];

    bool yayınla = false;

    if (başlık.length > 0)
    {

        Gönderi gönderi = Gönderi(başlık, içerik);

        gönderi.kaydet();
        yanıt.redirect("/");
    }
    else
    {
        yanıt.redirect("/gönderiler/oluştur");
    }
}
```

I'd like to make basic form validation. For example if input fields are empty it redirects to previous page.

I suppose I should pass some error message to the create method like *baslik field should not be empty* etc..

But since I am quite new to framework I shouldn't figure out. Are there any facilities does the framework offer for form validation.

Answer (score 0):

Basic form validation is easy when you use the web framework from vibe.d. The basic steps are:

1. Create a class `Gönderiyi` and put your `kaydet` method inside this class:

   ```
   class Shipment {
       @method(HTTPMethod.POST)
       void kaydet() { ... }
   }
   ```
2. Define a method inside the class which should be called in case a validations fails. This method should display the error message:

   ```
   void getError(string _error = null, HTTPServerResponse res) { ... }
   ```
3. Annotate the `kaydet` method with the `@errorDisplay` attribute to connect the method with the error function:

   ```
   class Shipment {
       @method(HTTPMethod.POST)
       @errorDisplay!getError
       void kaydet() { ... }
       void getError(string _error = null, HTTPServerResponse res) { ... }
   }
   ```
4. Now do the validation inside the `kaydet` method and throw an exception in case of an error. The `getError` method is then called automatically. You can take advantage of parameter binding and conversion, too. When the D parameter name is the same as the name of an HTML input value, then this value is bind to the D parameter. Automatic type conversion takes place (e.g. to `int`) and can lead to exceptions, which are then handled in the `getError` method, too.
5. As last step you need to register your class with the web framework:

   ```
   auto router = new URLRouter;
   router.registerWebInterface(new Gönderiyi);
   ```

You should have a look at [the documentation of errorDisplay](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.web.web/errorDisplay) and at the [web framework example from vibe.d](https://github.com/vibe-d/vibe.d/blob/master/examples/web/source/app.d), too.